# Syntax highlighting problems in Scala Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, syntax-highlighting

I'm using the Obsidian theme from [Eclipse Color Themes](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) with the Scala Eclipse IDE, and everything looks great except for some values, which show up as a horrible dark blue that's extremely hard to read. It seems to happen for certain vals and not others, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly when it happens, so I don't even know what to look for in my Eclipse setting.

Here's a screenshot from an assignment I'm working on that shows some examples of the problem: [image]

That's from a Scala JUnit test suite (obviously), where it seems to occur more often than in the main program. I've also found that it rarely occurs in a Scala worksheet, even when the worksheet is an exact copy of the main file. There are instances in the main file of the dark blue highlighting, but the same instance in the worksheet has the correct (or at least, the expected) highlighting.

Any ideas? I'm guessing it might just be some incompatibility with the theme and the Scala IDE, but I really dislike the default ultra-bright theme, so I'm hoping to be able to use a darker theme without this annoying problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could set those in Preferences > Scala > Syntax Coloring > Scala (semantic)

- lazy local val
- lazy template val
- local val
- local var
- template val
- template var

I set all of those to the same color

Comment: Most of them don't work for me, e.g. I cannot get `var`s to have a different color.

Comment: What theme are you guys using on Eclipse now, looks like it is still the case, and eclipsecolorthemes.com seems to down